# Why popover fullscreen in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am using popover. But popover shows fullscreen iphone.
Here is the image

[image]

Here is the code:
Popover action:

```
 @State private var showPopover = false
            var body: some View {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showPopover = true
                }) {
                    Text("Show Popover")
                }
                .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                    PopoverView()
                }
            }
```

Here is popover:

```
        struct PopoverView: View {
        @State var adaptableHeight = CGFloat(100)
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Popover Content")
                Button("Dismiss") {
                    // dismiss the popover
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any project configuration issue?
what is wrong with the code...

Comment: This is the standard behavior for iOS. The popover I think you want only works on iPad or Mac. If you want a custom popover for iOS you have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you should use your own struct to use a popover on iPhone, if you run your code on an iPad you should see the popover you’re looking for. Hopefully Apple will fix that soon.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is now possible since iOS iOS16.4 with the `presentationCompactAdaptation` parameter. This article put me onto it: https://www.swiftyplace.com/blog/swiftui-popovers-and-popups

TL;DR:

```
.popover(isPresented: $show,
     content: {
Text("Hello world")
    .padding()
    .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
})
```